# fitting rich text box's text into print page c#

Tags: c#, printing, richtextbox

I am new in C# and I am trying to print richTextBox's text into a page with size 58x297 but the text always starts from the middle of the page. I checked the printer properties but I couldn't find anything wrong. My aim is to print the text of my rich text box at the very left and top point of the page. I believe the problem is the initial spacing because of the size of my page that is 58x297 spacing is normal for an A4 page but not for mine.
This is the piece of work that I am trying to make work

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument documentToPrint = new PrintDocument();
    printDialog.Document = documentToPrint;

    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
        documentToPrint.OriginAtMargins = false;
        documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Document_Print);
        documentToPrint.Print();
    }
}

private void Document_Print(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
    float LinesPerPage = 0;
    float YPosition = 0;
    int Count = 0;

    float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
    float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
    string Line = null;
    Font PrintFont = this.richTextBox1.Font;
    SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    LinesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

    while (Count < LinesPerPage && ((Line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        YPosition = LeftMargin + (Count * PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Line, PrintFont, PrintBrush, LeftMargin, YPosition, new StringFormat());
        Count++;
    }

    if (Line != null)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }

PrintBrush.Dispose();

}
```

It would definitely be great if you have any ideas about. Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Your code printed to the top left corner for me.  Try a different printer.

Comment: Thanks but Can you please tell me is there any space on the top and left side of your printed page? I actually don't want any space to display. I want my text directly start without any space. Can you think of a way to do it ?

Comment: I focused on your phrase `text always starts from the middle of the page`.  Are you changing the question?

Comment: Actually my page size is 58x297 so an A4 paper may look normal but in the 58x297 size page, a normal space for A4 paper comes to the middle of the page. So the problem is still starting from the middle but according to the 58x297 size paper. I believe the problem is the spaces that causes my text start from the middle. I am sorry for the confusion. But I still don't know how to fix it. Should I change my question?

Comment: Did you mean to use `YPosition = LeftMargin...`?  Looks like you want `YPosition = TopMargin...`

Comment: I also tried it with TopMargin but still the same.

Comment: Use the PageSettings.Margins property to change the default.